# EJS View Not Rendering

Tags: javascript, view, rendering, ejs

I am trying to load ejs templates in my express app. I set the 'view engine' to ejs and, passed an ejs template to the response.render. However,when I am navigating to localhost:8000, I am only seeing the include statements in literal form.

The template file:
index.ejs

```
{% include('commonheader') %}
<div id='mainbody' class='container-fluid'>
  <nav>
    {%- include('mainheader', {
      navbar: navbar_options
    }) %}
  </nav>
</div>
{%- include('commonfooter', {
  footer: sitemap
}) %}
```

commonheader.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <title><%= title %></title>

    <!-- bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet"
    href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u"
    crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!-- bootstrap js -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Jquery -->
    <script
              src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
              integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
              crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- Custom stylesheets and js -->
    <%- if(stylesheets){
      if(typeof stylesheets == []){
        Array.prototype.forEach(function(sheet){
          %}<link rel='stylesheet' href= {%= sheet %}>{%
        }, stylesheets);
      }
      else{
        %}<link rel='stylesheet' href= {%= Array.prototype.shift.call(stylesheets) %}>{%;
      }
    }; %}
  </head>
  <body>
```

commonfooter.ejs

```
<footer>
  <% if(footer){
    for(let k in footer){
      if(typeof footer[k] []){
        Array.prototype.forEach.call(function(link){
          %}<a href= {%= link['href'] %}>
            <li>{%= link['name'] %}</li>
          </a>{%
        });
      }
      else{
        %}<a href= {%= link['href'] %}>
          <ul>{%= link['name'] %}</ul>{%
      }
    }
  %}
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

routes.js

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const appinst = express();
const _template_dir = '/static';
const _root_addr = '127.0.0.1:8000';

// bind render engine to ejs
appinst.set('views', path.join(__dirname,'views'));
appinst.set('view engine', 'ejs');


appinst.get('/', function(request, response){
  response.render('index', {
    css_stylesheets: [
      'css/index.css',
    ],
    navbar_options: [
      {
        'href': _root_addr + '/',
        'name': 'Home'
      },
      {
        'href': _root_addr + '/create',
        'name': 'Create'
      },
      {
        'href': _root_addr + '/howto',
        'name': 'How To'
      }
    ],
    sitemap: [
      {
        'href': _root_addr + '/',
        'name': 'Home'
      },
      {
        'href': _root_addr + '/aboutus',
        'name': 'About Us'
      },
      {
        'href': _root_addr + '/create',
        'name': 'Create'
      },
      {
        'href': _root_addr + '/howto',
        'name': 'How To'
      },
      {
        'href': _root_addr + '/contactus',
        'name': 'Contact Us'
      }
    ]
  });

});
```

Browser Output:

```
{% include('commonheader') %}
{%- include('mainheader', { navbar: navbar_options }) %}
{%- include('commonfooter', { footer: sitemap }) %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you mistyped the inclusion, should look like this:

```
<%- include('mainheader', { navbar: navbar_options }); %>
```

but from your code you're missing the opening and closing tag `<%-` `%>`

you're only using the `%-` and `%`

```
{%- include('mainheader', { navbar: navbar_options }) %}
```